# Reactor Kafka is causing the interruption of consumer messages from random partitions

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, project-reactor, reactor-kafka

Seems like a persistent issue with my reactive Kafka consumer—it intermittently halts message consumption from different partitions.

A restart temporarily fixes the problem, but it resurfaces after some time. Despite experimenting with various Kafka consumer properties, the root cause remains elusive.

Any help or insights would be highly appreciated.

```
    private val kafkaGlobalConfigProperties = kafkaGlobalConfigProperties()

    fun initialize(
        consumerTopic: String,
        consumerGroup: String,
        consumerAutoOffset: String,
        maxPollSize: Int,
        maxPollIntervalMs: Int,
        concurrency: Int,
        maxDeferredCommits: Int,
        commitBatchSize: Int,
        bufferMaxSize: Int,
        commitInterval: Long,
        maxPartitionFetchBytes: Int? = 1 * 1024 * 1024,
        operation: suspend (record: ReceiverRecord<String, ByteArray>) -> Unit
    ) {
        val kafkaReceiver = kafkaReceiver(
            consumerGroup = "test-consumer-group",
            consumerAutoOffset = "latest",
            maxPollSize = 1000,
            maxPollIntervalMs = 300000,
            consumerTopic = "test-topic",
            commitBatchSize = 2000,
            commitInterval = 0,
            maxDeferredCommits = 3000,
            maxPartitionFetchBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024
        )

        kafkaReceiver.receive()
            .flatMap({
                mono {
                    executeWith(operation, it)
                }.retryWhen(Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(2)))
                    .onErrorResume { ex ->
                        it.receiverOffset().acknowledge()
                        log.error("Error in processing record: ${ex.message}", ex)
                        Mono.empty()

                    }
            }, concurrency)
            .retryWhen(
                Retry.indefinitely()
            )
            .doOnError { error ->
                log.error(error) { "received error in reactive stream pipeline $error" }
            }
            .buffer(bufferMaxSize)
            .repeat()
            .subscribe()
    }

    private suspend fun executeWith(
        operation: suspend (record: ReceiverRecord<String, ByteArray>) -> Unit,
        it: ReceiverRecord<String, ByteArray>
    ) {
        try {
            operation(it)
            it.receiverOffset().acknowledge()
        } catch (ex: TimeoutCancellationException) {
            log.warn("Record processing timed out: ${ex.message}")
            it.receiverOffset().acknowledge()
        }
    }

    private fun kafkaReceiver(
        consumerGroup: String,
        consumerAutoOffset: String,
        maxPollSize: Int,
        maxPollIntervalMs: Int,
        consumerTopic: String,
        commitBatchSize: Int,
        commitInterval: Long,
        maxDeferredCommits: Int,
        maxPartitionFetchBytes: Int?
    ): KafkaReceiver<String, ByteArray> {
        val consumerProperties = consumerProperties(
            consumerGroup, consumerAutoOffset,
            maxPollSize, maxPollIntervalMs, maxPartitionFetchBytes
        )
        val receiverOptions = ReceiverOptions.create<String, ByteArray>(consumerProperties)
            .subscription(setOf(consumerTopic))
            .commitBatchSize(commitBatchSize)
            .commitInterval(Duration.ofMillis(commitInterval))
            .maxDeferredCommits(maxDeferredCommits)
            .addAssignListener { partitions ->
                partitions.forEach { partition ->
                    log.info(
                        "Assigned partition: ${partition.topicPartition().partition()} " +
                            "on topic ${partition.topicPartition().topic()}"
                    )
                }
            }
            .addRevokeListener { partitions ->

                partitions.forEach { partition ->
                    log.info(
                        "Revoked partition: ${partition.topicPartition().partition()} " +
                            "on topic ${partition.topicPartition().topic()}"
                    )
                }

            }

        return KafkaReceiver.create(receiverOptions)
    }

    private fun consumerProperties(
        consumerGroup: String,
        consumerAutoOffset: String,
        maxPollSize: Int,
        maxPollIntervalMs: Int,
        maxPartitionFetchBytes: Int?
    ): Properties {
        val consumerProperties = Properties().apply {
            put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaGlobalConfigProperties.bootstrapServer)
            put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, consumerGroup)
            put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer::class.java)
            put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer::class.java)
            put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, consumerAutoOffset)
            put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollSize)
            put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, maxPollIntervalMs)
            put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_PARTITION_FETCH_BYTES_CONFIG, maxPartitionFetchBytes)
            put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false")
        }
        consumerProperties.putAll(kafkaGlobalConfigProperties.credentialsConfig())
        return consumerProperties
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you found the cause? I am seeing the same issue where a consumer stops consuming data randomly.. Restart fix's this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: What is your concurrency in flatmap?

Comment: Also could you tell me the load per sec and your poll and max fetch records also why not add on back pressure buffer operator with appropriate size

Comment: hello JayGhiya. apologizes for the delay. my concurrency is set to the topic size. 
@Surajit Chongder.. did you find the solution for this issue ?